# What is the purpose of keystore

Tags: ssl, keystore

Normally a cacert is used as a truststore which means a base where we put certificates of other servers so that we will authenticate them (we trust connection from these servers only if they use the same certificate as in truststore).

Whereas, a keystore is normally used for storing keys (they are used when we behave as a servers).

But the problem is that I find in the internet commands for adding certificates too in keystore and that there's no basic functionality in keytool for adding a private key in keystore.

So, I start wondering if I did misunderstand the purpose of a keystore and it's role. Can anyone tell me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Technically a KeyStore and a TrustStore are of same type. They just serve different purposes based on what they contain.

A `KeyStore` is simply a database or repository or a collection of Certificates or Secret Keys or key pairs. When a KeyStore contains only certificates, you call it a TrustStore.

When you also have Private Keys associated with their corresponding Certificate chain (Key Pair or asymmetric keys), it is called a KeyStore.

There are different types of KeyStores the JCE provider supports:

- **JKS (Java Key Store)** --> When you have only certifcates, it is a TrustStore. When you also have Private Keys associated with the certificate chain, it is a KeyStore.
- **JCEKS (Java Enhanced Key Store)** --> These can store what JKS can store and additionally Secret Key (Symmetric Key) too. You cannot store secret keys in JKS type KeyStore's.
- **PKCS12** --> This is like a KeyStore but a different type called PKCS12. These can store Private Keys along with their certificate chains. But the standard is to have 1 Entry only, i.e, 1 Private Key and its associated certificate chain.

Their purposes can are broad, but generally used for these purposes:

- **JKS** - Securing your web server.
- **JCEKS** - Store your encryption keys (symmetric), can also be used to secure web server.
- **PKCS12** - When a web server is setup for Two-Way SSL, it requires the clients to authenticate to the server. In these cases, the client would generate a KeyPair, and generate a CSR (PKCS10) from it and have it signed by a Certificate Authority (CA). The client is then given a certificate chain, which the client associates it with his PrivateKey in a PKCS12 KeyStore. It can then be used to make the SSL connection.

Comment: You would not issue a PKCS12 to a client. The client would build his own. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.